# Am i mapping through this Reddit API wrong? Nothing printing

Tags: reactjs, api, reddit

I am working on an app that will eventually let a user search top posts on Reddit. I mapped and connected the API correctly however, the page is just not printing anything out.

I tried a lot with no success. Reddit API response is very deeply nested, and I even tried a loop in order to get every item and loop through them.

**App.js:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, Component } from 'react'
// get our fontawesome imports
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'

import './App.css'
import Subreddit from './Subreddit.js'

const App = () => {
  const [subs, setSubs] = useState([])
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('')
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    getSubs()
  }, [query])

  const getSubs = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`https://www.reddit.com/r/${query}.json`)
    const data = await response.json()
    console.log(data)
    setSubs(subs.data)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 className="header">
        Reddit <i className="fa fa-reddit"></i>{' '}
      </h1>

      <form>
        <input type="text"></input>
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>

      {subs.map((subs) => (
        <Subreddit
          title={subs.children.name}
          subreddit={subs.children.subreddit}
          post={subs.children.data.selftext}
          url={subs.children.data.url}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Do you mean by nothing printing like on the console variable `data` or not rendering the component's expected result for `.map()`?

Comment: just not rendering component. I used another apithe same way and it worked. my other issue with Reddit is that before I mapped it only was printing one array of the arrays - hence my idea for a loop since i want all children arrays of the object not just the first one

Comment: Can you show your API response JSON format?

Comment: ty i already solved this=]